# Flatten jagged array in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an elegant way to flatten a 2D array in C# (using Linq or not)?

E.g. suppose

```
var my2dArray = new int[][] {
   new int[] {1,2,3},
   new int[] {4,5,6}
};
```

I want to call something like

```
my2dArray.flatten()
```

which would yield

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note this is actually a jagged array and not a 2D array.  Thus you cannot limit the size of the inner arrays.  Your code would not compile unless you remove the 3 in `new int[][3]`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary you are right, thanks for picking me up on that :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
var flat = my2dArray.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
```

This will work with a jagged array like in your example, but not with a 2D array like

```
var my2dArray = new [,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

But in that case you can iterate the values like this

```
foreach(var item in my2dArray)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: Yup that does the trick, perfect! I am still a bit confused about the real 2D arrays, they don't seem very convenient to use...

Comment: @CedricDruck The difference is that a jagged array's second dimension can vary where as a 2D array has a fixed size for both dimensions.  Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays) for more details.

Comment: The linked question confirms ... I'll stick to jagged arrays. I've been using those in multiple other languages anyway. The nicer syntax may be useful in some cases, but one can easily work without it... Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @CedricDruck You might want to just  switch to lists like `List<List<int>>` the advantage is that you can easily add and remove elements, but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Indeed, in this case the size of the collection is fixed, so no need. But in general I prefer using more flexible structures such as List or Dictionary.